# Would the Geas spell work in a dead magic zone once you enter it?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic

So I am not quite sure if *geas* would still be in affect in a DMZ, or do the damage if the command is not followed.

It is quite confusing as some players say that it wouldn't, and others say it would. I can't really figure it out myself, because I am 50/50 on it.

What happens to the *geas* spell in a dead magic zone?

Comment: @Someone_Evil [Dead magic zones are a real Forgotten Realms thing](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Dead-magic_zone). (At least, they were in previous editions.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## *Geas* does not work in a DMZ

The 'rules' for Dead Magic Zones (DMZ) can be found in the Weird Locales<sup>1</sup> table on page 109 of the *Dungeon Master's Guide*:<sup>2</sup>

> Dead magic zone (similar to an *antimagic field*)

So looking at [*antimagic field*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/antimagic-field):

> **Spells.** Any active spell or other magical effect on a creature or an object in the sphere is suppressed while the creature or object is in it.

And as [*geas*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/geas) is a continuous spell (i.e. has a duration) it is suppressed while the creature is in the DMZ. Being suppressed is explained as

> While an effect is suppressed, it doesn't function, but the time it spends suppressed counts against its duration.

so it should not force the command, nor deal any damage for failure to comply.

---

1: A set of some fantastical things a DM can put in the Wilderness of their world to make it more, or in this specific case less, magical.

2: If your DM is using different rules for DMZs I can't help you.

Comment: Interesting, so a low-cost way for a commoner to resist a Geas would be to wait for the duration to expire in a DMZ.

Comment: @MatthieuM., that's 30 days in a DMZ. Hope you got some henchmen or companions to protect you.

Comment: @Cœur that's not less than 30 days, and if it's cast at iirc 9th level, the duration is "until dispelled".. so going to be a bit hard for anyone to hang out in a dead magic zone for who knows how long..